# Laravel how to correcly extend a vendor class?

Tags: laravel, oop, composer-php

I need to override a class in a package installed with composer. Which is the best way to proceed? The class that I need to extend is:

```
namespace League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators;
```

I don't want to modify it directly for obvious reason, can I just extend the class from a controller?

Comment: Since it looks like a validator I would make a folder in app/ like app/Validators and add the class there like class AuthorizationValidators extends League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators and work from there. I did that a couple of times and it worked, but now I kinda regret that because I made changes that now I have to maintain

Comment: if it's a controller, otherwise make a separate class and extend `AuthorizationValidators`

Comment: @Indra I create the class that extend but is not called automatically

Comment: What do you mean by "not called automatically"? Probably, you want to give some more context within your question?

Comment: Of course it's not. You need to use the new class in your validator calls